# Как лучше распознать самописную каптчу на c#

Tags: c#, искусственный-интеллект, recaptcha

Есть задача по распознаванию текста по капче, я убрал ненужный шум с картинки и получил такой результат. Я пробовал использовать OCR Tesseract, Aspose, Iron, но они не дают необходимой точности. .Как улучшить распознавание в iron или уже писать свою и, но тогда лучше ее обучать на dataset из каптч или можно на mnist, но как тогда сказть что эо точно строка из 5 цифр ?

```
 var Ocr = new IronTesseract();

                Ocr.Language = OcrLanguage.EnglishBest;

                using (var Input = new OcrInput())
                {
                    Input.AddImage(ReplaceColors(downloaddatapath + "image.png", 100, Color.FromArgb(0, 102, 153), Color.Black));
                    Input.EnhanceResolution(300);
                    var Result = Ocr.Read(Input);

                    string str = Result.Text;

                    Bot.Send(driver, "//input[contains(@id,'captcha')]", str);
                }
```

Comment: Показали бы хоть пример капч. Я так понимаю, там сразу несколько задач. Нужно выделить из картинки собственно капчу. Потом поделить её как-то на символы. И потом уже эти символы распознавать по отдельности. Строить модель, распознающую сразу 5 символов - ну, такое. Хотя тоже можно загнаться и натренировать, но модель будет тяжёлая довольно. Mnist, кстати, не очень корректный датасет и он довольно своеобразный.

Comment: Ссылка на картинку: https://postimg.cc/K4qhk8Lb А какой тогда датасет вы бы посоветовали?